# What is the best word to define the profession of one who deals with photo editing and manipulation?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, photography

I mean the person who manipulates/edits images for a magazine, for example, or for an ad, outdoor, for a photographer or whatever.

Photo editor is what comes to mind, but it sounds to me like something old, coming from the time newspapers were the main media for delivering news.

A more modern term probably exists...

Comment: "Photo retoucher" may fit for a photo editing operator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***[Photoshopper](http://www.yourdictionary.com/photoshopper)*** is a term that is used with the meaning you are suggesting:

> - Someone who photoshops.
> - One who digitally alters photographs.

Usage examples:

> - 1999, Anne B. Keating & Joseph Hargitai, The Wired Professor, A Guide to Incorporating the World Wide Web in College Instruction, NYU Press, p 98:
>     *Each band is composed of a Hypertextualist, a Multimedium, and a Photoshopper, and these form “guilds” for working in the computer lab.*
> - 2004, L'Architecture d'aujourd'hui, nn 350–351, University of Michigan, p 104:
>     *The theorist Brett Steele sees in Mies van der Rohe the fist ‘Photoshopper’, the architect who anticipated our present-day modes of producing and processing imagery.*

([Wiktionary](https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/Photoshopper))

Answer (score 2):

***Graphic Artist*** or ***Graphic Designer*** is the official job title for one who holds this profession.

Comment: OK, but I think graphic artist or graphic designer is more generic. Photoshopper is more specific... thanks anyway. +1